# Execute sqlpackage.exe (which has few dependent dlls) while creating installer using WIX

Tags: c#, wix, dacpac

I need to deploy dacpac while installing database using WIX. For the purpose, I have considered to run SQLPackage.exe command with necessary switches so I have embedded the necessary exe and dlls using binary tags as follows

```
<Binary Id="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.11.dll" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Tasks.Sql.11.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.11.dll" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Utilities.Sql.11.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities.dll" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac.dll"/>
    <Binary Id="SqlPackage" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\SqlPackage.exe"/>
    <Binary Id="SqlPackage.exe.config" SourceFile="..\DeployDBs\DAC\SqlPackage.exe.config"/>
```

And calling the SqlPackage.exe using the custom action as follows

```
 <CustomAction Id="DeployMyDb" BinaryKey="SqlPackage" 
              ExeCommand="/a:publish /sf:&quot;MyDacpac.dacpac&quot; /tsn:localhost /tdn:MyDb" 
              Execute="immediate" />
```

The custom action is sequences to run after 'InstallFinalize' as follows

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="DeployMyDb" After="InstallFinalize"/>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>
    </Product>
```

When the dacpac is deployed (ie the custom action is run), it throws the 'FileNotFoundException' for the assembly 'Microsoft.Data.Tools.Utilities which is one of the embedded binary.

Please advise on the missing steps or additions things needed to be done to run this exe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution.

Instead of above approach, I created a separate project for custom action and added the references to the required binaries (ie the Binaries I previously mentioned in <binary> tags) and added the corresponding dll formed in the binary tag and called it via <CustomAction>

The resultant solution is as follows:

```
<Binary Id="InstallerWix_CustomAction.CA.dll" SourceFile="..\InstallerWix_CustomAction\bin\Debug\InstallerWix_CustomAction.CA.dll" />

<CustomAction Id="DeployDb" BinaryKey="InstallerWix_CustomAction.CA.dll" 
                 DllEntry="CustomAction1"                   
                  Execute="immediate" Return="check" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="DeployDb" After="InstallFinalize"/>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Comment: How did you wind up embedding the SqlPackage.exe?

Comment: In the custom action project. I embedded SqlPackage.exe as well as the related other binaries.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to implement this by adding the dacpac file as a binary, reading that binary in the CustomAction, and finally using 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac' (available on nuget) in my C# custom action.

I had to write the binary file stream into a MemoryStream for use with the DacPac.Load function.  The binary stream was an internal type of 'RecordStream' that was unusable by the Load function.  For your purposes, you may also want to modify the dacOptions variable to give you the desired result.

See my examples below:

Project.wxs:

```
<Binary Id="Database.dacpac" SourceFile="$(var.ProjectDir)\Database.dacpac" />

<CustomAction Id="DeployDacpac" BinaryKey="CustomAction.dll" DllEntry="DeployDacpac" Execute="immediate" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
  <Custom Action="DeployDacpac" After="InstallFinalize" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

CustomAction.cs:

```
[CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult DeployDacpac(Session session)
    {
        try
        {
            string sql = string.Format("SELECT Data FROM Binary WHERE Name = 'Database.dacpac'");

            View view = session.Database.OpenView(sql);

            view.Execute();
            var dataStream = view.First()["Data"] as Stream;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[dataStream.Length];
            int bytesRead;
            while ((bytesRead = dataStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) ;
            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                var dacOptions = new DacDeployOptions();
                dacOptions.BlockOnPossibleDataLoss = false;
                dacOptions.DropDmlTriggersNotInSource = false;
                dacOptions.DropObjectsNotInSource = false;

                var dacServiceInstance = new DacServices(GenerateConnectionString(session["SQLSERVER"], session["SQLDATABASE"], session["SQLUSER"], session["SQLPASSWORD"]));
                using (DacPackage dacpac = DacPackage.Load(ms))
                {
                    dacServiceInstance.Deploy(dacpac, session["SQLDATABASE"], upgradeExisting: true, options: dacOptions);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            session.Log(ex.Message);
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }
        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```